# NetBeans no me permite importar las clases

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, maven, glassfish

Dentro de mi proyecto web en el paquete de recursos el servlet solo me permitio importar una de las clases (la clase Comic) siendo que deberia dejarme importar todas ya que estan en el mismo paquete (source Packages).
esta clase comic se construye con elementos de las otras clases (las del paquete entities). Pero cuando las llamo no solo no puedo importarlas, si no que el ArrayList y la Connection con tiran una alerta amarilla (la de ArrayList me dice que esta declarada pero no la estoy usando, la Connection me dice "convert to try whit resources)

(cabe destacar que el mismo codigo en una aplicacion java de prueba funciona, por lo que descarto que sea un error de sintaxis)

```
            package com.mycompany.webcomic.servlet;

            import com.mycompany.webcomic.entities.Comic;
            import com.mycompany.webcomic.utils.ConnectionManager;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.sql.Connection;
            import java.sql.ResultSet;
            import java.sql.SQLException;
            import java.sql.Statement;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import javax.servlet.ServletException;
            import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


            @WebServlet(name = "comicservlet", urlPatterns = {"/comic"})
            public class comicservlet extends HttpServlet {




                @Override
                protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {

                    try{

                        ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
                        Connection con = connectionManager.getConnection();


                        Statement stm;
                        ResultSet rs;
                        String sql;

                        sql = "SELECT * FROM comic, categorias, autor, estados, users WHERE com_cat_id = cat_id AND com_est_id = est_id AND com_autor_id = autor_id AND com_user_id = user_id";

                        stm = con.createStatement();
                        rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

                        ArrayList<Comic> listaComics = new ArrayList<>();

                        while(rs.next()){
                            Comic comic = new Comic();

                            comic.setComicTitulo(rs.getString("com_titulo"));

                            Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
                            categoria.setCatID(rs.getInt("cat_id"));
                            categoria.setCatNombre(rs.getString("cat_nombre"));
                            comic.setComicCategoria(categoria);

                            Autor autor = new Autor();
                            autor.setAutorId(rs.getInt("autor_id"));
                            autor.setAutorNombre(rs.getString("autor_nombre"));
                            comic.setComicAutor(autor);

                            Estado estado = new Estado();
                            estado.setEstadoId(rs.getInt("est_id"));
                            estado.setEstadoNombre(rs.getString("est_nombre"));
                            comic.setComicEstado(estado);

                            User usuario = new User();
                            usuario.setUserId(rs.getInt("user_id"));
                            usuario.setUserName(rs.getString("username"));
                            usuario.setUserPass(rs.getString("user_pass"));
                            usuario.setUserNombre(rs.getString("user_nombre"));
                            usuario.setUserEmail(rs.getString("user_email"));
                            usuario.setUserFoto(rs.getString("user_foto"));
                            usuario.setUserDescripcion(rs.getString("user_desc"));
                            comic.setComicUser(usuario);

                            comic.setComicDescripcion(rs.getString("com_descripcion"));
                            comic.setComicFecha(rs.getDate("com_fecha"));
                            comic.setComicFoto(rs.getString("com_tapa"));
                            comic.setComicId(rs.getInt("com_id"));






                            listaComics.add(comic);               

                        }

                         stm.close();
                        rs.close();
                        con.close();
```

Las opciones que me da para solucionarlo son:
- create class "ejemplo" in package com.mycompany.webcomic.servlet (source package
- create class "ejemplo" in package com.mycompany.webcomic.servlet.comcicservlet
-search dependency at maven repositories
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alertas amarillas no son errores. Son advertencias de posibles problemas que tengas en tu código o mejoras recomendadas como es el caso de: "convert to try with resources". Fuera de esto debe funcionar.

Comment: el codigo funciona bien hasta que empiezo a desarrollar el while. Mi mayor problema es con las alertas rojas de las clases... por que me deja importar una y no el resto si estan dentro del mismo paquete

Comment: Agrega la estructura de paquetes de tu proyecto y el texto del error que tienes al importar las clases.

Comment: @E.Betanzos ahi lo agregue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que no has incluido el `import` correspondiente para ninguna de esas clase, al contrario de como si lo hiciste con la clase `Comic`: `import com.mycompany.webcomic.entities.Comic;`

Puedes hacer dos cosas para solucionarlo.

**1- Agregar un `import` por cada clase del paquete `entities`**

```
import com.mycompany.webcomic.entities.Categoria;
import com.mycompany.webcomic.entities.Autor;
import com.mycompany.webcomic.entities.Estado;
import com.mycompany.webcomic.entities.User;
```

**2- Agregar un solo `import` para todo el paquete**

```
import com.mycompany.webcomic.entities.*;
```

Comment: el problema es justamente que no me permite importarlos. por mas que incluya la linea de codigo me tira error

Comment: Si puedes importar `Comic` y el resto de las clases del paquete no, aún agregando el `import` correspondiente, es porque dichas clases no tienen visibilidad `public`. Asegúrate de agregar el `public` en la definición de cada clase.

Comment: SIIIIIIII <3 amigo gracias. como no me di cuenta jaja